# How to draw 2d geometric object (circle, polygon...) in php

Tags: php, image, geometry

I want to create very simple **2d geometric object** like circles and polygon. And print it to the screen like an image.
How can i do with **PHP** ?
Maybe with PHP Gd, then how ?

Comment: There are also some nice javascript libraries for this.

Comment: @syck can you give an example, that i can use on html pages ?

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: you dont need PHP. Use JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few native PHP functions to do this, but you really shouldn't be doing this in PHP.

You would need to create a blank image canvas via. `imagecreatetruecolor`, save it into the the directory of the server and fill it using some native image function such as `imagefilledpolygon`. PHP has built in `imagefilled___` functions you can use.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledpolygon.php